# Customized Blog/Latest Posts Page

Tags: customization, themes, configuration

This question is sparked by some issues I'm running into using Elementor, but it's not an Elementor-only question.

I'm trying to create a customized static blog page/latest posts page. I currently have one on my site that works properly; I just want a spiffier-looking one.

I've always assumed that a latest posts page is simply a static page into which WP inserts stuff. But when I created a new page and added some content to it, and set it as the latest posts page in Settings -> Reading Settings, it failed to display excerpts of the blog posts. The custom content I added showed up just not the posts.

This held true even when the "customized" page was totally blank (i.e., newly created and unmodified by me in any way).

In playing around I noticed that, at least for some themes, you need to set the latest posts page within Appearance -> Customize. Interestingly, when I go that route, and set the new/blank page as the latest posts page, it shows up exactly the way I expect in the customization window -- the post excerpts are showing -- but when I navigate to the page on the site after publishing the customizations the excerpts are once again missing.

Based on my years of experience writing software (mostly in C#) this feels like there's some hidden setting somewhere I'm missing, or that what I think of as "just a blank page" must be created through a different mechanism (perhaps by the theme when it installs?).

But I'd really like to be able to customize my latest posts page :).

Comment: It sounds like there may be a conflict with your theme or maybe Elementor. Is there a settings page specific to either Elementor or the theme that might set how the latest-posts page is displayed? Hard to diagnose more without knowing your full setup :)

Comment: LOL! That could certainly be the case. Unfortunately, I haven't found any specific settings related to latest post pages in the Elementor configuration settings. Perhaps more importantly, the problem manifests itself on the (presumably simple) 2020 theme that comes bundled with WordPress. So while it could be a theme compatibility issue, if so it involves a pretty basic theme.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. It was the bozo on the keyboard (i.e., me) not understanding how WordPress operated and how its configuration settings interact.

The first problem was simple. When I created a new "latest posts" page (in Elementor) it **was** displaying the list of blog posts...but because I didn't update the link setting in the menu item for 'Blog' I never saw it. Instead, clicking Blog in the menu dutifully took me to the previously-used latest posts page...which because it wasn't set in Settings -> Reading Settings as the latest posts page displayed nothing. As it should have. Updating the menu link for Blog -- so it pointed at my new latest posts page -- solved the problem.

Along the way I also noticed that the Elementor styling was being ignored when the new page was displayed. That was caused because I had set the page to be an "official" latest posts page in Reading Settings. Which overrode all the content in the custom page, replacing it with a default list of posts. The solution to this was to leave the "latest posts" page undefined in Reading Settings and use Elementor widgets to add the latest posts list to the new custom page.

Leaving that "latest posts" setting undefined results in a warning (which isn't terribly clear). But it appears to be a warning you can safely ignore.